# Client SMS on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, sms

I would realize an app that send and receive sms, saving them.

My app implements all thing suggested by this link: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

When user choise this app as default he should send and receive sms.

The send works correctly.

To write into provider i use this code:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED)){
            String address, str = "";
            SmsMessage[] msgs = getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            if (msgs != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    address = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    this.addSmsToSentBox(context, str, address, true, false);
                }
            }  
        }
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phoneNumber);
values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put("body", message);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

How can i receive sms? So i could save them into sms provider.